# Upvote Count Inconsistent even after F5/refresh

Tags: bug, voting

Note: I am not going to rerun this experiment. There was no intentions for mass upvotes.

F5 is feature to update count, I accept. What I meant is that upvotes given simultaneously are only recorded as +1 even after refresh/F5.

Conducted a test were, simultaneously 2 different users clicked Upvote at the same time to the same question.

**Conclusion:** Though total upvote count should be 2, if initial was 0. But only 1 count was recorded.

Tested the same simultaneous event to Like a Picture in Facebook, and it stored successfully both the likes clicked at the same time on the same picture and displayed correct total likes count.

I have also checked the upvote count after hitting F5. The count only increments by +1 instead of +2

**Note:** I am not generating false or mass Upvotes to anyone question or answer. I came up to test it because I am having similar problems with my website. For me, its related to DB concurrent reads and write issue. And I am reverting back to the original state of the question/answer upvote count after test.

Comment: Hit F5. Also, don't do organized voting.

Comment: @CodeCaster It wasn't organised voting. I was making a feature in my website, where I found this issue of concurrent writes. So, tested in SO and found the same issue. Even F5 results in only +1 instead of +2.

Comment: @AndrewMorton ok. I will conduct some more tests to check this bug.

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha Please don't. Agreeing for several people to vote on a post _is_ organized voting, even if you're only doing it as an experiment. Instead, find someone who has >1000 points, who can see the vote counts (who can see the total number of upvotes and downvotes).

Comment: Regarding your edit: are you aware that votes are locked after 5 minutes?

Comment: @S.L.Barth I just tested with 2 accounts. And no plans to increase the number of accounts. And I am reverting back the count states. I understand the exploit of it. Will be grateful if some SO tester can check it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth So, for 5 mins, upvotes are stored in some sort of log files and every 5 mins, its counts for individual questions/answers are calculated and updated?

Comment: No, I think upvotes are stored as soon as they reach the server. But you can't _undo_ an upvote or downvote after 5 minutes. So if you do this experiment (which I do **not** recommend), you should revert your votes within 5 minutes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth About reverting, I did within 5 minutes. Can someone check my issue in SO? As following everyone here, I wont further re run this test as it causes complexities.

Comment: To be fair, this could be a valid bug report. Since apparently F5 did not update the vote count from two different accounts. @AayushKumarSingha, thank you for not continuing the experiment. I trust that you did not mean harm, but it was still against SO rules.

Comment: if this bug is true, then the whole upvote count is incorrect. Many upvotes may not be counted, and for downvotes, which I never tested, may have same issue

Comment: _"upvotes given simultaneously are only recorded as +1"_ - you do understand that this is a very bad bug request? Please include all relevant details. Which accounts were used, what is their reputation, what was the message they received upon voting, and so on. My guess is that one of the accounts has not enough reputation to vote (_"Your vote won't be counted but was recorded"_ or whatever it says), or there is some mechanism in place that prevents simultaneous votes from the same address, as a buggy proxy server or fraud workaround.

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha: I *strongly* doubt that. I'm someone who sees a lot of votes go by in a  day, and I haven't noticed any problems with people wanting to vote. Are you a) sure you were not logged in with the same account and b) did both users see the upvote button highlighted after reloading? I also must caution you not to try and test this again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am **not trying to re run the test** as others already mentioned its disadvantages. I am sure I was not logged in with same account. and after refreshing, it highlighted but count only incremented by 1.

Comment: Did your second account really had 15 reputation points ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

SO doesn't reload the vote count when you vote on an answer, it just adds / subtracts one from the total.

Refresh the page to see the actual vote count.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a vote go up by two when I voted. This might have been because it was simultaneous with the SignalR push of another vote.

Comment: @CodeCaster: That's possible, but not triggered by your own vote.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a "feature". It is more the deliberate lack of a feature. It is entirely possible to track the voting data with more live updates, just it would cost development effort (and maybe bandwidth) to patch the edge case. We already have live updates for incoming new answers and edits for example.

Comment: @NeilSlater: Meh, semantics.

Comment: Even after F5, upvote count only incremented by +1. The expected count increment is +2. I am not concerned about f5. Refreshing also not recording the change of +2. @Cerbrus

Answer (score 2):

As @CodeCaster and @Tensibai pointed out, the problem was with privilege. My friend's account which was the second account didn't have 15 reputations. That caused the problem.
I am **not at all planning** to re run the test with 2 different valid accounts.